# Error:'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: numpy, load

quick question. I encounter error as ***"'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)"*** when run *"numpy.loadtxt"* to load below content.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yTbA.png)

below is Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "C:/Users/g/Documents/instance/main_foud.py", line 8, in <module>
    a_raw = np.loadtxt('D:\personal\stock\量比\资金流向统计\各股\GG主力增仓0105.txt')   
File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 943, in loadtxt
    first_vals = split_line(first_line)   
File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 919, in split_line
    line = asbytes(line)   
File "C:\Users\g\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\py3k.py", line 35, in asbytes
    return str(s).encode('latin1') 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Can someone help me to figure out what problem is? Appreciate for your answer!

Comment: Scripts section:a_raw = np.loadtxt("D:\personal\stock\量比\资金流向统计\各股\GG主力增仓0105.txt")
print(a_raw.decode("latin1").encode("UTF-8"))

Comment: Can someone help me?